# Google TTS - Text to speech in Android OS error

Tags: android

I was wondering and I really don't know why text to speech in android sometime is very smoothly but sometime(rarely) has error and popup message Google Text-To-Speech engine has stopped and then my device is getting stuck until the popup appear and close, then I can continue my next activity.

You has another code that supported all android device about speech engine (google and samsung)?

Here is my code that I am using:

Class Level:

```
private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
private TextToSpeech tts;
```

onCreate Level:

```
//check for TTS data
Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

When Button is Press:

```
String speech_question = getResources().getString(R.string.question_1);
speakWords(speech_question);
```

The end of Class Level:

```
private void speakWords(String speech) {
    //speak straight away
    tts.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            //the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        }
        else {
                //no data - install it now
            Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
            installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installTTSIntent);
        }
    }
}
//setup TTS
public void onInit(int initStatus) {
        //check for successful instantiation
    if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        if(tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    }
    else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

The code above is working very very well but sometimes when I try refresh activity again and again, and press button to speech the text again and again, then my SamSung Galaxy S3 was give me the error result is Google Text-To-Speech engine has stopped and then my device is getting stuck until the popup appear and close, then I can continue my next activity.

My question is, do you have another method to use TTS that support all device?

The Error Picture in Galaxy S3 as bellow.
[image]

Comment: Can you please post the output of logcat when the error on the S3 device oocures?

Comment: Okay please wait.. i will print screen and upload here.

Comment: Unfortunately, the screenshot isn't helpful. It would be helpful to read your logcat output. You can get your logcat output from commandline on your computer with adb: adb logcat More info for logcat here: https://www.open-sourced.de/show_article.php?articleid=52

Comment: Dear Alex, if you launch it and test it with emulator, I didn't get any error with TTS. :(

Comment: Ok, i understand this. But you get an error on your device. So you can connect it with a cable to your computer after your app crashes and read out the log with adb like this adb logcat   So you can get a more specific errormessage to determine what went wrong.